# Simple daemon with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, daemon

I've got a symfony2 (php framework) app for which I've written a command that can be called from the command line. This command simply checks a table in the database for a task, then executes that task. What I need is a daemon-like creature that will enable this command to be run in the background whenever a row is inserted into this (mysql) database table. I can't do this with a cron job because the tasks required need to happen as quickly as possible, and will often need to happen in parallel.

Am I looking at this all wrong?

Server: Ubuntu 11.10
PHP: 5.3
Symfony: 2.1
mysql: 5.1.66

Comment: The scenario I ran into once was a SQL Server trigger with xp_cmdshell. Huge problems when a lot of lines got inserted (i.e. bulk insert). I keep to the polling fashion, sometimes with a plain old cronjob, sometimes with a python daemon that allows me to poll more frequently than once a minute.

Comment: Would a database trigger work in your case? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you are using some kind of a ORM for persistence. I would then probably use a hook like postInsert() in [Propel](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/propel.html)

> postInsert() code executed after insertion of a new object

or postPersist() in [Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html).

> postPersist - The postPersist event occurs for an entity after the entity has been made >persistent. It will be invoked after the database insert operations. Generated primary >key values are available in the postPersist event.

Here is some more information on [lifecycle events](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events).

Answer (score 1):

Even if this is a very old question...
I've found https://github.com/mac-cain13/daemonizable-command

Probably useful for what you need to do.